# How can I delay this specific line of code?

Tags: java, minecraft

So I'm working on my Triggerbot for Minecraft.
In order for it to bypass, I need to add a slight delay...
I've done some research and tried some different things, but I can't seem to get anything to function, as if I use:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException TriggerDelay) {
    TriggerDelay.printStackTrace();
}
```

That essentially freezes the entire game, and not just the line of code I want to delay...

Here's the specific section I need to delay, I left out the rest so kids can't skid my Triggerbot..

```
if(mc.objectMouseOver !=null) {
    if(mc.objectMouseOver.typeOfHit == MovingObjectType.ENTITY) {
        if(mc.objectMouseOver.entityHit instanceof EntityLivingBase) {
            // This is where I need help, I want to delay the following by 100ms...
            mc.thePlayer.swingItem();
            mc.thePlayer.sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new C02PacketUseEntity(mc.objectMouseOver.entityHit, C02PacketUseEntity.Action.ATTACK));
```

Comment: I hope that indentation is not from your actual code. How many levels of nested loops and conditions do you have there?

Comment: Look into threads. If you just want to schedule the execution of those two operations for later you could create a background thread and sleep that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps closer to what you need, but I'm not 100% sure minecraft will love you for it

```
if  ( mc.objectMouseOver != null
   && mc.objectMouseOver.typeOfHit == MovingObjectType.ENTITY
   && mc.objectMouseOver.entityHit instanceof EntityLivingBase) {
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                mc.thePlayer.swingItem();
                mc.thePlayer.sendQueue.addToSendQueue(new C02PacketUseEntity(mc.objectMouseOver.entityHit, C02PacketUseEntity.Action.ATTACK));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

- a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), which has the ability to schedule tasks at arbitrary points in time;
- implementations of [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s which can act the way you want.

For the first point, look at the [`Executors` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), which gives the ability to create them; as for the second point, ensure that your `Runnable`s have all the necessary data to perform the task at hand.

And that's it, really.

One important thing to consider and which is not obvious is that both `ScheduledExecutorService` and `Runnable` define only the *behaviour* but do not have the authority, nor do they have the intent, of defining the *state*.

The `Executors` class provides you with ways to create `ScheduledExecutorService`s whose state is managed for you; but the `Runnable`s you submit to them are yours to define, state included.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeUnit.seconds.sleep(int seconds);`  or `TimeUnit.minutes.sleep(int minutes);`

Read more about why this is the most easy-to-use recommended method to use instead of `Thread.sleep(long miliseconds);` here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2012/11/What-is-timeunit-sleep-over-threadsleep.html

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the article you linked to provides much benefit in a situation where the sleep time is almost certainly going to be less than 1 second and even in extreme cases a few seconds at most.